# Need help understanding GeneratorOf and SequenceOf in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I am having extreme difficulty understanding how **GeneratorOf** and **SequenceOf** work in Swift. I tried looking up the documentation, but they have limited or no explanations of it. Can someone with knowledge of these functions/protocols explain how they work in the following example:

```
enum TaskListRow: Int, Printable {
    case ScaleQuestion = 0
    case NumericQuestion


    /// Returns an array of all the task list row enum cases.
    static var allCases: [TaskListRow] {

        var caseIndex = 0
        let caseGenerator = GeneratorOf { TaskListRow(rawValue: caseIndex++) }


        // Create a sequence that will consume the generator to create an array.
        let caseSequence = SequenceOf(caseGenerator)


        return Array(caseSequence)
    }

    // MARK: Printable
    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .ScaleQuestion:
            return NSLocalizedString("Scale Question", comment: "")

        case .NumericQuestion:
            return NSLocalizedString("Numeric Question", comment: "")

        }
    }

}


let taskListRows = TaskListRow.allCases
print(taskListRows) //prints list
```

Also, how does **GeneratorOf** and **SequenceOf** call the *description* computed property?

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I found a blog post that has helped answered my question:

[Swift Sequences and Lazy Evaluation](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/06/26/swift-sequences.html)

Here is supplemental documentation that covers a broader definition of **GeneratorOf** and **SequenceOf**:

[Swift Collection Protocols](http://nshipster.com/swift-collection-protocols/)

Comment: See also this website for more documentation: http://swiftdoc.org/type/GeneratorOf/